# Не удается клонировать чужой репозиторий на гитхабе (доступ есть)

Tags: git, github

Ввожу `https://github.com/имяАккаунта/названиеРепозитория.git`
пишет ошибку **zsh: no such file or directory: [https://github.com/ИмяАккаунта/ИмяРепозитория.git](https://github.com/%D0%98%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%90%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0/%D0%98%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F.git)**

Если ввожу `gh repo clone ИмяАккаунта/ИмяРепозитория`, то пишет
**GraphQL: Could not resolve to a Repository with the name 'ИмяАккаунта/имяРепозитория'. (repository)**

Не могу разобраться, уже пол дня сижу в гугле. Если это важно, у меня мак

Comment: Почему все так любят сидеть полдня в гугле, вместо того, чтобы потратить 10 минут на чтение документации... 

Comment: В командную строку нужно вводить не `https://...`, а `git clone https://...`, тогда не будет ошибки `zsh: no such file or directory`.

Answer (score 0):

Если есть доступ к репозиторию, то лучше всего заходить по SSH.
Более подробно это описано здесь: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

И здесь (на русском):
https://sendel.ru/posts/https-to-ssh-on-github/?ysclid=l7mgq6j8vo917323711

Все должно работать

Comment: **clip < ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
Copy
это скопирует публичный ключ в буфер обмена.

если данная команда не работает, откройте файл id_ed25519.pub в любом текстовом редакторе, и скопируйте все содержимое файла, публичный ключ выглядит так** Команда не работает, файл на маке найти не получается, как будто его и не создвалось, хотя он создался и путь к нему даже написан. но его там нет. скопировал содержимое папки из примера на сайте и вставил на гитхаб. пишет : **Key is invalid. You must supply a key in OpenSSH public key format**

Answer (score 0):

Вы пишете в консоль `https://github.com/<аккаунт>/<репозиторий>.git`, а это не является командой, что приводит к указанной ошибке:

```
bash: https://github.com/<аккаунт>/<репозиторий>.git: No such file or directory
```

Чтобы склонировать git-репозиторий по https, выполните команду [git clone](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-Git-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F#r_git_cloning):

```bash
git clone https://github.com/<аккаунт>/<репозиторий>.git
```

Comment: ошибка 403 **Cloning into 'freeio'...
remote: Write access to repository not granted.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/имяаккаунта/имяфайла.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403** . ввел потом git config --list. аккаунт тот, на который разрешили доступ

Comment: В исходном вопросе вы неправильно вводили команду, я указал в ответе, как нужно правильно вводить команду git clone и приложил полезную ссылку на русском для вас. Если у вас другой вопрос с новым текстом ошибки, то создайте новый вопрос, нажав на "Задать вопрос" вверху страницы.